# STS Spring plugin on Eclipse Juno installation

Tags: eclipse, spring, plugins

I am having problem with installation of STS plugin on my Eclipse Juno instance. I am running windows 7 64 bit with 64 bit eclipse and 64 bit java. 
Eclipse is installed outside Program Files directory
Error message that I am getting:

Unable to read repository at
http://dist.springsource.com/release/TOOLS/update/e4.2/compositeContent.xml

I have tried everything listed here https://issuetracker.springsource.com/browse/STS-2890

Comment: Did you use **http://dist.springsource.com/release/TOOLS/update/e4.2** as installation site? I can access that definition file.

Comment: @Kane yes this is the link that was used for installation, I can access both files as well, however eclipse can not...?

Comment: I tried above url. It works fine. I'm using Eclipse 4.2.1. Your network probably has problem to access that site.